# SQL - I need make a condition that restrict the select to show only lines that correspond both conditions

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have my select and I need two conditions, they are:

```
and item.group not in (100)  
and item.subgroup not in (120)
```

what I need is that, the select shows me only items that both conditions match.
In the way that i wrote, items that are from group 90 and subgroup 120 aren't being shown, but they need to be.
Can someone help me? :D
I have no clue how to make both conditions match each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
and not (item.group in (100) and item.subgroup in (120))
```

Or equivalently, `or`:

```
and (item.group not in (100) or item.subgroup not in (120))
```

Note that both of these might need to be tweaked if the values can be `NULL` -- depending on how you want the `NULL` values treated.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
where (group, subgroup) not in ((100, 120))
```

---

For example (based on Scott's `emp` table):

```
SQL> select deptno, ename, job from emp order by deptno, job;

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
        10 MILLER     CLERK
           CLARK      MANAGER
           KING       PRESIDENT
        20 SCOTT      ANALYST
           FORD       ANALYST
           ADAMS      CLERK            --> omit DEPTNO = 20
           SMITH      CLERK            --> and JOB = CLERK
           JONES      MANAGER
        30 JAMES      CLERK
           BLAKE      MANAGER
           MARTIN     SALESMAN
           WARD       SALESMAN
           ALLEN      SALESMAN
           TURNER     SALESMAN

14 rows selected.
```

Let's try it:

```
SQL> select deptno, ename, job from emp
  2  where (deptno, job) not in ((20, 'CLERK'))
  3  order by deptno, job;

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
        10 MILLER     CLERK
           CLARK      MANAGER
           KING       PRESIDENT
        20 SCOTT      ANALYST            --> right; no Adams nor
           FORD       ANALYST            --> Smith (clerks) in DEPTNO = 20
           JONES      MANAGER            --> any more
        30 JAMES      CLERK
           BLAKE      MANAGER
           ALLEN      SALESMAN
           WARD       SALESMAN
           TURNER     SALESMAN
           MARTIN     SALESMAN

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
where item.group not in (100, 120) and item.subgroup not in (100, 120)
```